# Proving Banach's fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems, cauchy-sequences

[image]

The hint tells me how to proceed but I am stuck.

I define the sequence ${z_n}$ as is stated in the hint,

First off, I want to prove that $|z_{n+k} - z_n| < \epsilon$

I add $z_{n+k-1}$ and subtract it (adding zero) so I get

$|z_{n+k} + z_{n+k-1} - z_{n+k-1} - z_n|$

Can I use the triangle inequality on this? When do I invoke the contraction ?

Comment: $$z_{n+k} - z_n = \sum_{m=1}^k z_{n+m} - z_{n+m-1}$$

Comment: No. $|T^{n+k}z - T^nz| =| T^n(T^kz -z)| \le C^n | (T^kz -z)|$. Now use $C<1$

Comment: Please check the standard sources on the web for this theorem. Chances are that you not only find a hint or two, but also explanations of the proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer how does that summation help me?

Comment: The idea is to compare the sequence with a geometric series, $|z_n-z_m|\le (k\cdot c^n-k\cdot c^m)$ for $n<m$. This gives a kind of majorant criterion for sequences in metric spaces.

Comment: @Thomas Ah I understand now! Could you write that statement equivalently using the sequence $z_n$ instead of the mapping $T$?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert z_n - z_{n-1}\rvert \leqslant \lvert z_1-z_0\rvert \sum_{k=0}^\infty c^k$$

Comment: @DanielFischer ah I see, and since $ 0 < c < 1$ the right side can be replaced by $\epsilon$ . perfect!

Comment: @terribleatmath $z_n = T^n z$. You have an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that $|z_{n+k}-z_n|<\epsilon$ for $n$ big enough. First you note that
$$
|z_{m+1}-z_m|=|T(z_m)-T(z_{m-1})|<c\,|z_m-z_{m-1}|<c^2\,|z_{m-1}-z_{m-2}|<\cdots<c^m\,|z_1-z_0|.
$$

Then you have
$$
|z_{n+k}-z_n|=\left|\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}z_{n+j+1}-z_{n+j}\right|\leq\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}|z_{n+j+1}-z_{n+j}|<\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c^{n+j}\,|z_1-z_0|\\
=c^n\,|z_1-z_0|\,\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c^j=c^n|z_1-z_0|\,\frac{1-c^k}{1-c}\leq\,c^n\,\frac{|z_1-z_0|}{1-c}
$$